# Isomorphism $\text {Rep}_{G,k}\cong \space \text {Mod}_{k[G]} $

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a  group and $k$ a field.

**Proposition**: There is an isomorphism of categories $F:\text {Rep}_{G,k}\rightarrow \space \text {Mod}_{k[G]} $.

I begun by proving that there is a functor $\text {Grp} \rightarrow \text {Alg}_{k}$ by extending the inclusion assignment $G \mapsto k[G] $ by the universal mapping property with $f : k[G] \rightarrow A $ where $A$ is a $k$-algebra. Now I hope construct a chain $\text{Rep}_{k,G}\rightarrow \text {Grp} \rightarrow \text {Alg}_{k} \rightarrow \text {Mod}_{k[G]}$ such that the chain is an isomorphism of functors. I am stuck at this point. I can't get a grip on how to show an isomorphism for objects and morphisms. Should I try to construct the reverse chain and show it it the "inverse" or is there a more efficient way to approach the problem?

Comment: Don't try building that chain; it doesn't exist. You should somehow get a $k$-bilinear $k\left[G\right]$-action out of a $k$-linear $G$-action and vice versa. There's only one reasonable choice... (Don't worry too much about morphisms until you've constructed the functor on objects. Morphisms in many cases come easily afterwards.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually more is true: Let $k$ be a commutative ring (think of a field if you want to) and $M$ be a monoid (e.g. a group). There is an isomorphism of categories $\mathsf{Rep}_{M,k} \cong \mathsf{Mod}(k[M])$ *over* $\mathsf{Mod}(k)$. This means: If $V$ is some $k$-module, then giving an action of the monoid $M$ on $V$ is *the same* as giving a $k$-linear action of the $k$-algebra $k[M]$ on $V$ (and similar with homomorphisms, see below). The proof is an immediate consequence of the universal property of the monoid algebra $k[M]$: An action of $M$ on $V$ is a monoid homomorphism $M \to \mathrm{End}_k(V)$. This corresponds to a $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[M] \to \mathrm{End}_k(V)$. But this is precisely a $k$-linear action of the $k$-algebra $k[M]$ on $V$.

Explicitly, if $M$ acts on $V$, then $k[M]$ acts on $V$ via $\bigl(\sum_m \lambda_m \cdot m\bigr) \cdot v := \sum_m \lambda_m \cdot (m \cdot v).$

If $V,W$ are $k[M]$-modules, then a $k$-linear map $f : V \to W$ is $k[M]$-linear iff it is $M$-linear (one usually says $M$-equivariant) - this follows easily from the explicit description in the last paragraph, or one useses again the universal property of $k[M]$.

Answer (score 1):

This chain is not going to lead to the answer, I guess.

Let $V$ be a linear representation of $G$ over $k$, i.e. $G$ acts on the $k$-vector field $V$. Then let $F(V)$ be the naturally generated $k[G]$-module structure on $V$.

This mapping naturally extends to morphisms, and it admits an inverse: for a $k[G]$-module $M$ one can define both the $k$-vector space structure and the $G$-action in an obvious way, yielding the representation $F^{-1}(M)$.